# parse JSON data into listView

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, listview

1. How do I get my JSON data into my listview? All I am trying to do is loop through the JSON data and grab the first two elements and add them to my two text fields in my listview.

BUT when I do the code below it just puts the whole array element into both list views brackets and all. It increments but just the main array not the sub items. (if that makes sense)?

Below is my json data the magic happens after " **//Loop the Array**":

```
[["Ace Tattooing Co","80260","(303) 427-3522 ","461 W 84th Ave",""],["Think Tank Tattoo","80209","(720) 932-0124","172 S Broadway",""]]
```

This is my script so far:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ShowShop extends ListActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyApp";  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ziplist_layout);

         Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
         String shop_data = bundle.getString("shopData");
         Log.v(TAG, shop_data);

         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //Get the data (see above)
               try{
            //Get the element that holds the earthquakes ( JSONArray )
                   JSONArray jsonShopArray = new JSONArray(shop_data);


                        **//Loop the Array**
                for(int i=0;i < jsonArray.length();i++){                        

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONArray e = jsonShopArray.getJSONArray(i);

                Log.v(TAG, e.toString(i));
                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(1));
                map.put("name", "Store name:" + e.toString(2));
                map.put("zipcode", "Zipcode: " +  e.toString(3));
                mylist.add(map);
        }
               }catch(JSONException e)        {
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
               }

               ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.shop_list,
                       new String[] { "name", "zipcode" },
                       new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

       setListAdapter(adapter);




        /**Toast.makeText(ShowShop.this, zipReturn, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you define `map` variable?

Comment: Sorry left it out when i was coping it over. Updated.

Comment: `jsonShopArray` is actually `jsonArray`? :)

Comment: Are you using any library like jackson or gson ?

Comment: Updated to show the libraries you are correct Nikita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.toString` is incorrect http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#toString(int)

You should use `getString` or `getInt` or getWhatever

Comment: Get that was my issues. Thanks +1