# Why isn't the data showing up on my listview?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, json, listview

It's connecting and pulling the data from the json array. Its adding two listview items but not showing any text?

JSON array
{"tournaments":[{"Title":"my title","Contact":"my contact","Description":"my description","City":"my city","State":"Kansas","Category":"Roulette"},{"Title":"my title","Contact":"my contact","Description":"my description","City":"my city","State":"Connecticut","Category":"Three Card Poker"}]}

And some of my code in java...

```
    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://kleinefrosch.com/retrieve.php");

    try{

        JSONArray  tourneys = json.getJSONArray("tournaments");

        for(int i=0;i<tourneys.length();i++){                       
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = tourneys.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("Title:" , e.getString("Title"));
            map.put("Contact:" , e.getString("Contact"));
            map.put("Description:" , e.getString("Description"));
            map.put("City:" , e.getString("City"));
            map.put("State:" , e.getString("State"));
            map.put("Country:" , e.getString("Country"));
            map.put("Category:" , e.getString("Category"));

            mylist.add(map);            
        }       
    }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                    new String[] { "Title","Contact","Description","City","State","Country","Category" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
            Toast.makeText(JsonActivity.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: UPDATE Why is this guys working and mine not? we are using the same example code  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155322/parse-json-data-into-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));`

Hope it runs then.

**EDITED**

Your Mistake is Here

```
map.put("Title:" , e.getString("Title"));
```

it should be

```
map.put("Title" , e.getString("Title"));
```

As it is Key which will be Matched in  SimpleAdapter. 
Like this remove `:` from each string value.

So please make sure that both the Keys match perfectly.

Comment: It runs its just not showing the text. no exceptions or anything

Comment: @user1411823 : Have a look at Edited portion

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that JSON string parsing is completed without any exceptions, I think that you should use this construction:

`setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects);`

For more info about go to [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Post your Xml code, are you using any Customized Listview? If it is means add some Dark color for Textview.